# How to deploy a truffle app in heroku?

Tags: truffle, dapps, ropsten, truffle-deployment

I have working truffle app that interacts with **Ropsten Testnet** but currently, I'm on my local machine environment at `localhost:3000`.

I want to deploy this app to heroku such that my ropsten testnet stills works as expected. I tried googling a lot and also tired some of the stuffs but nothing came around that could to solve my problem.

Here is my `truffle.js` file:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var infura_apikey = "my api key";
var mnemonic = "some awesome mneumonic";

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*" // Match any network id
        },
        ropsten: {
            provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 
                      "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + infura_apikey),
            network_id: 3,
            gas: 400000
        }
    }
};
```

And, here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "decentralizedtodo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "truffle.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "lite-server",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Pramesh Bajrachaarya",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

This may be a noob question but, can someone please give a stepwise answer to the very process?

This will be helpful to me as well as future readers too.

Comment: my package.json is this, do i have to change anything to deploy to heroku? `{ "name": "truffle-init-webpack", "version": "0.0.2", "description": "Frontend example using truffle v3", "scripts": { "lint": "eslint ./", "build": "webpack", "dev": "webpack-dev-server" }, "author": "Douglas von Kohorn", "license": "MIT", "devDependencies": { "babel-cli": "^6.22.2", "babel-core": "^6.22.1", "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2", "babel-loader": "^6.2.10", "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0", "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8", "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0", "babel-register": "^6.22.0", "copy-webpack-plugin":

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the thing I'm trying to do cannot be done in Heroku.

**Why?**

It's due to [heroku ephemeral filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416738/how-to-use-herokus-ephemeral-filesystem).

Answer (score 2):

I've done it!

You need change your package.json

```
"start": "npm run test",
"dev": "lite-server",
"test": "lite-server"
```

And add a file bs-config.js with this code:

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT,
  files: ['.src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}'],
  server:{
    baseDir: ["./src", "./build/contracts"]
  }};
```

Good luck!

repo: https://github.com/bukosabino/truffle-voting-dapp-ropsten

url dapp: https://voting-dapp-ropsten.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing a small node server to serve my static files. This might work. Will try as soon as possible 

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be just another deployment like nodejs application. 
But just remember change the network in `truffle.js` to 
mainnet or ropsten or rinkeby. And also run `truffle migrate` on that network.

You could use [THIS LINK](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#view-logs) 
or
[THIS](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration)
for reference.

Comment: Yea, I have already changed the network in `truffle.js` and `truffle migrate --network ropsten`. Going to deploy it as a node app real soon. Have you tried this before?